# Cant assign my arsys domain to a AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, ipv4

**I want to assign an external domain (arsys.com) to my EC2 instance**

I bought a .eu domain from the arsys domain provider: "mydomain.eu".

I have an EC2 instance on AWS, with an elastic ip and public domain.

```
Public DNS: ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Public IPV4: 1.2.3.4
```

I have configured my domain for this machine in arsys.com this way:

Control panel -> Domains -> DNS Servers ->

- **Name DNS Server:** ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
  **IP:** 1.2.3.4

Control panel -> Website -> DNS ->

- **DNS Entry:** mydomain.eu **Type:** A **Value:** 1.2.3.4
- **DNS Entry:** www.mydomain.eu **Type:** CNAME **Value:** mydomain.eu
- **DNS Entry:** control.mydomain.eu **Type:** CNAME **Value:** pdc.servidoresdns.net

> when I access "mydomain.eu" through the browser, I get the error that this website cannot be accessed

I have configured the instance security group so that it allows anyone to access it through the HTTP protocol (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443).

I have also set up the ICMP protocol to be able to ping both DNS and IP.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Regardless of the configuration, it can take some time before a new domain name gets fully propagated. How long has it been since you registered it?

Comment: @Mahdi 
Already last friday

Comment: Can you Ping the domain name? Do you see the domain name resolved correctly to the IP of that instance you have on AWS?

Comment: @qkhanhpro I cant ping the domain name, but I can ping my public ip and the aws public DNS

Comment: @MaríaCristinaFernándezLópez the part where you said "Control panel -> Domains -> DNS Servers ->

Name DNS Server: ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com IP: 1.2.3.4"

Can you take  apicture and upload it to imgur? something may be wrong here

Comment: @qkhanhpro this is the [main page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FgfafQW5rA0tC3D4uMS5D6PApmGLRjQb/view?usp=sharing) and this the [DNS Server Page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s3i_XmprJq4cM3XP_uJF8nxUm88tWK_f/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is on this part

> Control panel -> Domains -> DNS Servers ->
>
> Name DNS Server: ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com IP:
>   1.2.3.4

The thing called `Public DNS: ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` of EC2 is not meant to be the address of a DNS server

What you just did is that: You specify to arsys that : Please let ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com manage DNS for my domain which is not possible

Please remove that line and let arsys manage your DNS. Or better, use CloudFlare / CloudFront to manage your DNS